# Запретить стирать в EditText несколько первых символов

Tags: android, android-edittext

Делаю чат. В нем можно ответить человеку и в `EditText` в начало вставляет типа `Ваня,` - обращение. Как можно сделать это обращение нестираемым?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такой вариант

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                EditText edit = (EditText) getCurrentFocus();
                if (edit != null) {
                    if (!s.toString().startsWith("Ваня,")) {
                        edit.setText("Ваня,");
                        Selection.setSelection(edit.getText(), edit.getText().length());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```